# Shutterfly API with a desktop app: how would callback work?

Tags: api, callback, desktop-application

I am trying to write a desktop app to go against the Shutterfly API. Both of their paths to get a token ('seamless' and 'interactive') involve the API sending the authorization token to a callback URL. Any thoughts or experience on how this would work for a desktop app that has no website component? Their documentation seems to indicate that their 'interactive' path was meant to support desktop apps.

Comment: You could consider a non-seemless/interactive sign in approach which shouldn't require callback. But you have to request a token for the login session and keep passing that around I think its documented in the API. But I don't know if it's mandatory to fill in the callback URL when you sign up to create a new application on Shutterfly API site.

Comment: Got the url for the documentation?